# Angular 2, input attribute is removed from DOM

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I've got a button that I can enable/disable via a binding:

```
<button [disabled]="model.disabled">Do Something</button>
```

I've got some styling that's dependent on that attribute, for example:

```
button[disabled] {
  background: red;
}
```

So far so good.

Now I attach a directive to that button which uses the disabled attribute an input:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[some-directive]"
})
class SomeDirective {
  @Input("disabled") disabled: boolean;
}
```

If I attach this directive to a node:

```
<button some-directive [disabled]="model.disabled">Do Something</button>
```

This strips the `disabled` attribute from the DOM, which breaks my styling.

Why is it doing this? Can I *stop* it from doing this?

[Plunker demonstrating this problem.](https://plnkr.co/edit/ShyxaDgoRnkitJq6RoCe?p=preview)

Comment: but [disabled] is a know Angular property, why would you need to make a directive? Name collision will occur also

Comment: I've reduced my problem to a simple example. I'm not creating a disabled directive. I have numerous controls and components in my code that can be  disabled via the `disabled` attribute. I also have a `tooltip` directive, which displays a custom tooltip. If the node that's attached to gets disabled, I need to know about it so I can dismiss the tooltip. So I make the `disabled` attribute an input. There should be no name collision. It's an *input*, not an output. I should be able to have 100 directives that watch that input and act on it if I wish.

Answer (score 0):

In your directive use another name for the input to avoid the conflict:

```
@Input("_disabled") disabled: boolean;
```

Then it works.